# Get secret_value from multiple hashes md5(known_value_n + secret_value)

Tags: hash, md5

The attacker knows multiple hashes like md5(known_value_n + secret_value), for multiple known values. Does it help him to discover secret_value better then just single md5(known_value + secret_value)? secret_value is long enough, 20-30 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, having multiple hashes will not make determining the secret which was hashed any easier.